# Adding git subtree from a branch

Tags: git, git-subtree

I'm trying to add a repo (called cow) to my project using `git subtree add`.  In particular, I'd like to add the branch `stable` (which is not the `master` branch).  I tried:

```
git subtree add -P cow https://github.com/geoffryan/cow.git stable
```

But this returned the error

```
'stable' does not refer to a commit.
```

I also tried:

```
git subtree add -P cow https://github.com/geoffryan/cow.git cow/stable
'cow/stable' does not refer to a commit.
```

And:

```
git subtree add -P cow https://github.com/geoffryan/cow.git ca26d248a12c21264e32a2c212381cafb578c9fb
'ca26d248a12c21264e32a2c212381cafb578c9fb' does not refer to a commit.
```

The hash was that for the latest commit in the `stable` branch.  The examples of use I've seen online all use `master` for the commit, is it possible to use `subtree add` on a non-master branch?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

This seems to work

```
$ git remote add cow https://github.com/geoffryan/cow.git
$ git fetch cow
$ git subtree add -P cow cow/stable
Added dir 'cow'
```

I don't understand how to use directly the command with the repository part.

Comment: But that pollutes the parent repo with a bunch of unwanted commits from the cow repo ... :-/

Comment: which are the unwanted commits?

Comment: That may be a little late but you can use --squash keep git subtree from replaying the whole log.

Comment: you might want then to add the `--squash` option such that git subtree will imports only a single commit from the subproject, rather than its entire history.

Comment: to clarify a bit since @rpattabi edited the answer: `--squash` it's not the  correct option IHMO bc if you use `git subtree` you usually want to maintain the original history, otherwise you can simply copy and commit the file as usual.

Comment: Is it possible to add a certain tag of the branch?

Comment: @BernhardDöbler do you mean connecting that tag to the corresponding new commint or attaching the tree from that tag?

Answer (score 0):

I encounter a similar problem. However, gipi's solution doesn't work for me. Oddly, when I add master branch everythins is fine, but when I want to add other branches, it returns

```
fatal: Couldn't find remote ref xxx/yyy
Unexpected end of command stream
```

So I tried another way:

```
mkdir tmp
cd tmp
git init
git clone url_for_xxx.git yyy
```

And `subtree add` from that temp rep's master branch:

```
git subtree add -P yyy /path/to/tmp/ master
```