# git subtree: possible to change subtree branch/path in a forked repository?

Tags: git, merge, repository, git-subtree

In a repository `A` the folder `sub` is included as git subtree of the repository `S` - pointing to `master` branch.

I have forked repository `A` into `F`. Now I want to do one of the following in `F`:

- change `sub` to use a different branch of `S` (ie `develop` branch)
- or: change `sub` to use a different repository altogether

Is either one of these possible, and if so, how? Will there be any side effects I should know of?

And how can I make sure my subtree change won't be updated in repository `A` when I merge my changes (pull request)? I mean besides isolating commits.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

If you used `git subtree` (and not `git submodule`) to create the subtree, then it's just a normal dir. To switch it to another branch, just delete it and recreate the subtree from the new branch. This is:

```
git rm <subtree>
git commit
git subtree add --prefix=<subtree> <repository_url> <branch>
```

That should work without problems.

Comment: and that won't be synched upstream? I guess I'll give that a try then.

Comment: It won't be synced upstream. The `<repository_url>` is not saved anywhere; it's just used for the command to know where to get the files from. After that, you get a normal subdir within your repository.

Comment: Ah ok, I see that now ... subtree simply "copies" the state of a commit of another repository, as if I had copied it manually (but preserving the commit history and what not). So that doesn't change my original problem of not synchronizing a specific folder between two repositories, but sufficiently answers this question.

Comment: Note: I think it's always best to add a remote before adding and pulling a new subtree. In my experience it works much better and can't be done after you add the subtree. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16829401/adding-git-subtree-from-a-branch

Comment: Since subtree is a folder you need to add -r to recurse it:
`git rm -r <subtree>`