# git subtree add: change prefix preserving local commits

Tags: git, git-subtree

is there an easy way to move a subtree added using the following cmd

```
git subtree add --prefix=<prefix> <repository> <commit>
```

in other terms, is it possible to change prefix from `dir1` to `dir2`.

the answer to [git subtree: possible to change subtree branch/path in a forked repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18536279/git-subtree-possible-to-change-subtree-branch-path-in-a-forked-repository) suggests to remove the subtree then add it back.

It doesn't work for me because I need to preserve local commits, is there another way?

Comment: With local commits you mean changes to the files in that subdirectory after you added the subtree?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One alternative is splitting from your current commit that include the local commits you want to preserve:

```
git subtree split --prefix=dir1 HEAD

# Create a branch with the printed commit just to use it later
git branch split_dir_1 <split_commit>
```

And then do what was described it in the [question you mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18536279/git-subtree-possible-to-change-subtree-branch-path-in-a-forked-repository), delete the subdirectory and re-add the subtree.

```
git rm dir1
git commit
git subtree add --prefix=dir2 . split_commit
```

Bear in mind that by doing this you will still be able to see in the repository history when the first subtree was created and deleted and re-added.

Comment: thank you for your answer, is it possible to do git subtree pull afterward with your method? I have to test it... will accept your answer if it works, thanks

Comment: Should be possible, yes. The `git subtree split` will preserve the original history of the subtree as long as there was no squashing involved in the subtree operations. You could push that new split branch to the original subtree repository, so it follows that you should be able to pull too.

Comment: In that case what you could still try is to do a `git subtree split`, and `push` the splitted commits to the subtree repository. That way you will have there the original subtree commits and the new content. Then again delete `dir1` and read the subtree in `dir2`.

Comment: ok, thank you! I'll check this method as soon as I have time (I already went the drop local commits way...)