# Right way to switch Git Subtree branch?

Tags: git, git-subtree, subtree

Assuming I have already added a new remote "foo", and pulled a subtree, squashed, with branch master.

```
$ git remote add -f foo some-repo.git
$ git subtree add --prefix=foo --squash foo master
```

From the articles I have read ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18536279/git-subtree-possible-to-change-subtree-branch-path-in-a-forked-repository), and [here](https://artemis.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/PD/pages/41648134/git+subtrees), etc), this appears to be the common way to switch branches. In this case, to branch "bar":

```
$ git rm -r foo
rm 'foo/file'.
...
$ git commit -m "Delete foo on branch 'master' to switch to branch 'bar'."
1350 files changed, 144703 deletions(-)
delete mode 100644 foo/file
...
$ git subtree add --prefix=foo --squash foo bar
git fetch foo master
From some-repo.git
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
Added dir 'foo'
```

But this feels dirty. Why not just use "git subtree pull" which already has a branch argument (no rm/commit/add)?

```
$ git subtree pull --prefix=foo --squash foo bar
From some-repo.git
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
Merge made by the 'recursive' strategy.
 foo/file                                                        |  2 ++
 ... smaller changeset output ...

 3 files changed, 41 insertions(+)
 ...
```

When I have tested both locally, I see no differences between the subtree dirs (./foo). Why is everyone recommending the way that adds more complex changesets and commits (removing and re-adding)? What am I missing, maybe some edge cases?

Answer (score 0):

`git subtree pull` was introduced in [commit 13648af5](https://github.com/git/git/commit/13648af5eecd0880a64b6ea4b14f485f53daa2f1) in April 2009 for Git 1.7.11 by [Avery Pennarun `apenwarr`](https://github.com/apenwarr).

> ### Add '`git subtree merge`' and '`git subtree pull`'.
>
> These are simple shortcuts for '`git merge -s subtree`' and '`git pull -s subtree`', but it makes sense to have it all in one command.

You can see in its [associated test](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a13a299996725a979f5a7d6bd878b0237de0f26d)

```
-git merge -s subtree subproj-merge-split3
+git subtree pull --prefix=subdir ../subproj subproj-merge-split3
```

This is not the same as rm/subtree add, which remains better suited to switch branch.

Comment: This didn't really answer my question (why one method over another for switching branches), but since I'm getting no other answers, you get the bounty.