# Finding which branch of my subtree that is checked out/added

Tags: git, git-subtree, subtree

In my git workspace I have a subtree module added. I learned from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18536279/git-subtree-possible-to-change-subtree-branch-path-in-a-forked-repository) how to change subtree branch. But I am not able to figure out which subtree branch that is currently checked out in my workspace.

I can list all my remote branches, including subtree remotes, but it does not say which of the subtree branches I do have in my workspace. Here it shows that I have master as my main dev branch, but no info for my subtree module "my_api".

```
> git branch --all
* master
  remotes/origin/master
  remotes/my_api/develop
  remotes/my_api/master
```

Does anyone know how git can report such information?

Comment: Subtrees simply do not have that kind of separate existence. Once the subtree is added, it's just part of the current commit, on the current branch. This is both their advantage—they are now just *there*, with nothing special to do—and their disadvantage: they are now just *there* and there is no way for Git to update them.

Comment: Thanks. Think I understand. Got to be more careful when adding, and know what I add for subtree I suppose.