# Why am I told that "'master' does not refer to a commit" when I use git-subtree?

Tags: git, git-subtree

When I enter `> git subtree add --prefix=<some dir> --squash <some repo> master` I receive the message `'master' does not refer to a commit`. If I change 'master' to a sha I still get a warning. The repo is valid and master exists in the repo that I am trying to pull in.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I eventually found [this commit](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1c3e0f007c8c18dd4ceda3c67cbfb8e01ef2c894) and the important bit of information is

> This patch:
>
> - relaxes the check the  argument in "git subtree add "    (previous code would not accept a ref name that does not exist locally too, new code only ensures that the ref is well formatted)

My problem was that my local repo does not have a branch named master (semantic versioning). **The simple workaround was to create a local branch named master** (or whatever the name of the branch that you are trying to pull from is. That resolves the issue seen here: [Adding git subtree from a branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16829401/adding-git-subtree-from-a-branch) Geoff Ryan could have created a local branch named cow and successfully used subtree)

This should hopefully be resolved by git 1.9 but, for anyone using an earlier version, I hope that this saves you some frustration.